# To make a Bookmark?

Tags: grammar

My book asked me to correct

> The materials for to make a bookmark cost only about 200 won.

So I gave the answer:

> The materials to make a bookmark cost only about 200 won.

However, my friend said that this was wrong, saying that the answer should be:

> The materials for making a bookmark cost only about 200 won.

The reason he gave was that if I write "The materials to make a bookmark cost only about 200 won," this implies that "to make" describes "the materials".

So, can someone tell me why my answer is wrong(or correct)?

Comment: Your answer *isn't* wrong. Your friend is. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+materials+to+make%22) are over 100,000 written instances of the noun phrase *the materials to make [something]*. And there are only a third of that number for [the materials **for making** (whatever it is)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+materials+for+making%22)

Comment: The friend is wrong {to say|for saying} the OP was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence, and your friend's alternative, are both acceptable and natural.

> The reason he gave was that if I write "The materials to make a bookmark cost only about 200 won," this implies that "to make" describes "the materials."

"To make a bookmark" or "for making a bookmark" do both describe "the materials."  This noun phrase starts "The materials" and the following four words answer the question *what materials?* So in that sense, "to make" or "for making" does describe "the materials."

If you wanted to talk about making the materials, you might say:

> To make the materials used in a bookmark costs only about 200 won.

This sentence has a different meaning and doesn't tell you how much it costs to *buy* the materials.  It may be that your friend thinks your sentence has a meaning similar to this, but it doesn't.  Your sentence and your friend's sentence both have the same correctness and meaning.